# Angular: how to use Storage from IonicStorageModule?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm new to Angular... I'm trying to configure a Singleton service here, following the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).

Well, my service needs to import Storage.
So I did this, but it's not working as I was expecting:

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';    
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ModalWeek } from './modal/modal';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Protocol } from './protocol';

let obj = {
  storage: Storage,
  weeks: new Protocol
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ModalWeek],
  exports: [ModalWeek],
  entryComponents: [ModalWeek],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    TaskServiceModule.forRoot(obj),  // *** my service *** //
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I get an error from VS Code saying:

> "Argument of type {storage: typeof Storage} is not assignable (...)
>   storage does not exist in type Storage"

**UPDATE**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Protocol } from 'src/app/protocol';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root', // it is a Singleton
})
export class TaskService { 
    private weeks: any
    private protocol: any

    constructor (private storage: Storage, protocol: Protocol) { 
        this.storage = storage
        this.protocol = protocol   
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at **[this docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage)**

Comment: I had read already... didn't help me much. I still don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `TaskServiceModule` (as the name indicates) is a Module, then it should first of all go into your `imports` array instead of your `providers`. Also it would be helpful to have a look at the `forRoot(...)` implementation of your Module, but I am pretty sure you won't even need it.

By importing the `IonicStorageModule` you already did what is required to use it's services inside your Module, since it exports the relevant services. For more information about that, you may want to have a look at [their docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage).

If `Protocol` is also a Service of yours, simply put it in the `providers` alongside with your other services, that you want to expose to your module, like so:

```
providers: [
    ...
    Protocol
]
```

Note, that this is effectively the same as decorating your Service with:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: AppModule
})
```

You may have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-angular-6-dependency-injection-providedin-vs-providers-85b7a347b59f) to get a better understanding of the different ways of dependency injection.

Now you may also choose to change the decorator of your `TaskService` from:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

to just:

```
@Injectable()
```

And therefore provide your service in your `AppModule`, like we covered for `Protocol` already. *I personally think that this gives you a better feeling of how Services are provided in Angular, especially if you are new to the topic.* Keep in mind that this is optional!

In order to give you better advice on how to solve your problem you would need to share more information about your project structure with us.

I hope this helps you already!

Comment: thank you so much, that "global understanding" was exactly what I was in need